# Get the selected items and validate the number of checked items?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using an  `ion-select` and I'm enabling the `multiple` attribute to select several options. I can not find a way to disable the rest of the options in real time if 3 options have already been checked. I am currently using the `ionSelect` event, but it only works when an option is checked. How can I solve my problem? How can I solve my problem? I would like to understand how I know how many options I have marked and get their value in real time.

This is my code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-8wewvd?file=pages/home/home.ts

**pages/home**

```
<ion-label>Select a person</ion-label>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="person" multiple="true">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let item of options; let i = index" 
    [value]="item.id" (ionSelect)="fn_checkOptions()" >
    {{item.name}}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>

export class HomePage {
public options:object=[];


constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
this.options= 
[
  {"name":"pedro","id":1},
  {"name":"juan","id":2},
  {"name":"maria","id":3},
  {"name":"velez","id":4},
  {"name":"yaya","id":4}
 ]
}

 fn_checkOptions(){
  alert("hey")
 }

}
```

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-flyqdr?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: do you want to find the result on each option click or after clicking the ok button?

Comment: after clicking the ok button... when I check/uncheck any option.

Comment: @AmiLinn  I intend to detect when each option is checked or unchecked, before clicking on the "ok" button

Comment: @AnandhSp I intend to detect when each option is checked or unchecked, before clicking on the "ok" button

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

Get a reference of our Ion Select as a [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) and search it's properties until I found where the values of the checked items are stored. `select._overlay.data.inputs` looks promising, but of course this may be subject to changes in future Ionic versions.

Once we got the inputs we can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) those who are actually checked and do our logic.

See the code here or as [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vmtcwf?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts).

HTML:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select a person</ion-label>
    <ion-select #select [(ngModel)]="person" multiple="true">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let item of options; let i = index" [value]="item.id" (ionSelect)="fn_checkOptions()">
            {{item.name}}
        </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Select } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('select', { read: Select }) select;

  public options: object = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.options =
      [
        { "name": "pedro", "id": 1 },
        { "name": "juan", "id": 2 },
        { "name": "maria", "id": 3 },
        { "name": "velez", "id": 4 },
        { "name": "yaya", "id": 4 }
      ]
  }

  fn_checkOptions() {
    let inputs = this.select._overlay.data.inputs;
    let checkedItems = inputs.filter(item => item.checked);
    if (checkedItems.length === 3) {
      // Disable checkboxes here
      console.log('Three checkboxes have been checked');
    }

  }
}
```